# How-to loop over JSON Arrays in postgresql 9.3

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm writing function for a new postgreSQL db and i'm trying to loop over a nested structure.

Is that even possible with the new JSON functions?
What i'm trying to do is here below:

```
DO
$BODY$
DECLARE
    omgjson json := '[{ "type": false }, { "type": "photo" }, {"type": "comment" }]';
    i record;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(omgjson)
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'output from space %', i;
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql
```

This returns a set of records (text!), that is not JSON! so i cannot query it like `i->>'type'`, but that's exactly what i want to accomplish...

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I was a little dumb, but the documentation on this json feature on postgresql website is actually minimal

to solve the problem all i did was

```
DO
$BODY$
DECLARE
    omgjson json := '[{ "type": false }, { "type": "photo" }, {"type": "comment" }]';
    i json;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(omgjson)
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'output from space %', i->>'type';
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: in later version of postgresql you can use jsonb_array_elements