# How to compare time interval (duration) in Postgres jsonpath

Tags: postgresql, jsonpath, postgresql-13

In the following example I have two objects on input. I want to select the one where duration between `start` and `end` is more that one day -> I expect object called `threeDays` to be returned.

How to write such condition in jsonpath?

`start` and `end` are date times.

I am using Postres 13.

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_array_tz('[
  { "name" : "oneDay", 
    "start": "2021-07-02 00:00:00",                                     
    "end":   "2021-07-03 00:00:00"
  },
  { "name" : "threeDays",
    "start": "2021-07-15 00:00:00",                                     
    "ende":  "2021-07-18 00:00:00"
  }
]'::jsonb, '$[*] ? (
    @.end.datetime() - @.start.datetime() > 1day     <-----  ???
).name');
```

Comment: This would be so easy with a properly normalized data model

Comment: may be this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272650/how-to-loop-over-json-arrays-in-postgresql-9-3

Comment: JSON Path doesn't know how to do date math (unless this is extension support by postgres).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using `jsonb_array_elements` and `->>` operator but w/o jsonpath.

```sql
select j
from jsonb_array_elements(
'[
  { "name" : "oneDay", 
    "start": "2021-07-02 00:00:00",                                     
    "end":   "2021-07-03 00:00:00"
  },
  { "name" : "threeDays",
    "start": "2021-07-15 00:00:00",                                     
    "end":  "2021-07-18 00:00:00"
  }
]'::jsonb) j
where (j ->> 'end')::timestamp - (j ->> 'start')::timestamp > interval '1 day';
```

Comment: maybe this is a way to go