# PostgreSQL retrieving a row for each item in a json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have two tables, `table_with_json` which has `id` and `text` column in which a valid json is stored that has structure like:

```
{
"workers":
 [
  {
  "name":"Anne",
  "email":"anne@somemail.com"
  },
  {
  "name":"Tom",
  "email":"tom@somemail.com"
  }
 ]
}
```

and `emails` table which has two columns:
`table_with_json_id` (a foreign key to table_with_json)
and
`email`

I need to fill up the emails table but I'm having trouble creating more than one row for each row in `table_with_json`

the result I want for above example would be inserting two rows to `emails` table

```
1 | id1 | anne@somemail.com
2 | id1 | tom@somemail.com
```

So far I've managed to get one row for every entry in `table_with_json`
with this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO emails (table_with_json_id, email) 
SELECT id, text::json->'workers'->0->'email' 
FROM table_with_json;
```

Comment: I think this is somewhat similar to your problem, so you should take a look if not already done : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20282427/11260467

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/GFoys4w3xW5q3sBbuoT85/0))

```
INSERT INTO emails (table_with_json_id, email) 
SELECT id, json_array_elements(text::json->'workers')->>'email'
FROM table_with_json;
```